# sql server like statement with char column

Tags: sql, sql-server, char, sql-like

I queried below statement but like statement not working for char(4) column (code). why? how solve it?I want to search all projects that their code liked @Code. for example project with code : 'FB01' , 'FB02' ,...

```
DECLARE @Code char(4)  = 'FB' ,

@CustomerID int   = null ,

@Name nvarchar (200)  = null ,

@CompanyID int   = null ,

@Status bit = null ,

@ProjectStatusID int = null,

@OrderBy nvarchar(50) = null ,

@StartRowIndex int ,

@MaximumRows int;


                WITH CompanyToProjectResult([ProjectID])
                AS
                (
                    SELECT [ProjectID] 
                    FROM [CompanyToProject] 
                    WHERE 
                    ([CompanyToProject].[CompanyID]= @CompanyID OR @CompanyID IS NULL)

                    GROUP BY [ProjectID]
                )

                SELECT
                    [Project].[ID] ID
                    ,[Project].Code Code
                    ,[Project].Name Name
                    ,[Customer].Name Customer
                    ,[Project].Status Status
                    ,[ProjectStatus].Name ProjectStatus
                    ,COUNT([Project].[ID]) OVER() [TotalRows]
                FROM
                    [Project] 
                    LEFT JOIN [Customer] ON [Project].[CustomerID] = [Customer].[ID] 
                    LEFT JOIN [CompanyToProjectResult] ON [Project].[ID] = [CompanyToProjectResult].[ProjectID]
                    LEFT JOIN [ProjectStatus] ON [Project].[ProjectStatusID] = [ProjectStatus].[ID]
                WHERE
                    (([Project].[Code] Like '%' + @Code + '%') OR @Code IS NULL)
                    AND ([CustomerID] = @CustomerID OR @CustomerID IS NULL) 
                    AND ([Project].[Name] Like '%' + @Name + '%' OR @Name IS NULL)
                    AND ([CompanyToProjectResult].[ProjectID] IS NOT NULL OR @CompanyID IS NULL)
                    AND ([Status] = @Status OR @Status IS NULL) 
                    AND ([ProjectStatusID] = @ProjectStatusID OR @ProjectStatusID IS NULL)  

                    ORDER BY  COALESCE(@OrderBy, '[Project].[ID] DESC') 
                     OFFSET  0  ROWS
                    FETCH NEXT  9   ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `varchar` instead of `char`. `char(4) = 'FB'` it is `'FB  '`

```
DECLARE @Code varchar(4)  = 'FB'
```